# Image selected from imagePickerController takes up whole screen instead of fitting inside of UI Image View [Swift]

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an image view that is programmatically created within a container view as such:

[Screen shot with circular profile image view inside container view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKqvB.png)

I have a button overlay on top of the profile image view to call the image picker controller. When an image is selected from the photo library, the image takes up the entire screen as below:

[Screenshot after image is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcYaq.png)

Here is the code for this view controller's viewDidLoad() and imagePickerController():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.profileBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: CGFloat(69.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(171.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(222.0/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1))

    //initializePrimaryUserData()

    fullNameTextField.text = self.primaryUser.firstName + self.primaryUser.lastName
    nickNameTextField.text = self.primaryUser.userName

    //create profile image view

    if hasProfilePic {
        profileImage.image = self.primaryUser.image
    } else {
        image = UIImage(named: imageName)!
        profileImage.image = image
    }

    profileImage.frame = CGRect(x: profileBackgroundView.bounds.midX, y: profileBackgroundView.bounds.midY, width: 100, height: 100)

    profileImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    profileBackgroundView.addSubview(profileImage)

    profileImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileBackgroundView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileBackgroundView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.width / 2
    profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
    profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    //create profileImageButton
    let profileImageButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: profileBackgroundView.bounds.midX, y: profileBackgroundView.bounds.midY, width: 100, height: 100))
    profileImageButton.setTitle("Photo", for: .normal)
    profileImageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileImageButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    profileImageButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    profileBackgroundView.addSubview(profileImageButton)

    profileImageButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileBackgroundView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileBackgroundView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        self.primaryUser.image = image
        self.hasProfilePic = true
        self.profileImage.image = image
        self.profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
self.profileImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```